# JavaScript - modal window with given html

Tags: jquery, windows, modal-dialog

how can I open a modal window using javascript only. I can't use own html-file so I have to pass html-data directly to method which will show window. Could you help me with this?

---

upd:
I can't use any own library.

Comment: Then don't use a library. But also don't ignore that libraries for this already exist. So go find one, or two, or twenty, and take the concepts/implementation you need (make sure you meet the conditions of the license, if any). There a number of different ways that this can be done. [Standing on the shoulders of giants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links found on google (only partially) related to the question that show this issue is not unique. They have not been reviewed.

http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/

http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodald3.htm

http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/2021/css-and-javascript-modal-dialogs

http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164247.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try a jQuery "lightbox-style" plugin. My favourite is [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) which does what you require. Example:

```
$.fn.colorbox({html:'<p>Hello</p>'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Library-less solution:

Make a div filled with content, style it so that it floats over your content and has `display:hidden` on page load.  With javascript set `myDialog.style.display = 'block'` and behold your modal.

This javascript may also add a background element that is styled to be translucent and to span the entire screen height and width, and blocks interaction to the page element under it.

In concept it's pretty simple really.  It's more CSS than JS, and the logic is simply showing/hiding the modal dialog element.

And there is lots of edge case improvement you can do with animating the element in, sizing it to fit content better, etc.  This is the sort of polish the libraries give you.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of simple javascript libraries out there to do this sort of thing.  [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) is pretty cool.